# How can I switch application language to the language of the current user?

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization

By default, WPF application uses the language of the system. How can I use the language of the current user in my WPF application?

**EDIT:** WPF Dispatcher by default uses current user language. This befavior is bug in my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [WPF multi-lingual](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20109/WPF-Multi-Lingual-at-Runtime) to see how you can dynamically switch the application locale at run time

Answer (score 0):

I need to use GetUserDefaultUILanguage function via Marshalling. C# CultureInfo class contains InstalledUICulture property, but it uses GetSystemDefaultUILanguage function and return system language.

**EDIT:** We can also use CultureInfo.UserDefaultUICulture via reflection.